# Can someone explain in detail or provide a video link that can help me understand how to sort a mongodb in react

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mern

I saw different versions but honestly they make no sense. I tried to implement them so I can understand it myself but I didn't know where I should put it at. does it go in my view main.js file or what file and then where in that file does it go.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Link } from '@reach/router'




const Main = props => {

   
    const [pets, setPet] = useState()

    useEffect((req, res) => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/users`)
            .then(res => {// does the sort go here
                // console.log(res.data.users)
                setPet(res.data.users)
            })
    }, [])

   // would the sort go before or in here ? 


    return (
        <div>
            These pets need a home:  do you know any other pets <a href="addpet"> Add Pet</a>
            <table className='table table-striped table-dark '>
                <thead className="">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>

                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        pets ?
                            pets.map((pet, i) => {
                                return (
                                    <tr key={i}>
                                        <td>{pet.pet_name}</td>
                                        <td>{pet.pet_type}</td>
                                        <td><Link to={`/viewpet/${pet._id}`}>Detail</Link> | <Link to={`/update/${pet._id}`}>Edit</Link></td>
                                    </tr>
                                )
                            })
                            : ''
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: setPet(res.data.users.sort((a, b) => a.pet_name < b.pet_name ? -1 : 1)

Comment: Would recommend you initialize your state with an empty array, that way you don't have to check for null, like this:
const [pets, setPets] = useState([]);
I changed the name to setPets instead since that is what you do, the variable you set it pets, not pet

Comment: that worked but can you explain it to me?

Comment: What about it do need explanation for?

Comment: (a,b) is that mean a the first pet_name and b the second or next pet_name

Comment: google for "javascript sort array on property value"

Comment: I can't give you you're props or close this post another reason for the explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @hellogoodnight and some help to other folks to help me understand what you were saying.

the answer was what you said :)

`setPet(res.data.users.sort((a, b) => a.pet_name < b.pet_name ? -1 : 1)`